# Axios first get the response and then render form TypeError: Cannot read property '***' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, axios

```
const [projectData, setprojectData] = useState();
useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get(`/fetch-project-details/${id}`, {
        headers: {
            "x-access-token": localStorage.getItem(`login`)
       }
    }).then((response) => {
        let result = response.data.recordset;
        setprojectData(result[0]); // store array in state projectData
    });
},[]);


return (
    <div>
    <h1>{projectData.title}</h1>
    ... other code

);
```

I am getting ** TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined **

How to first get the data and then pass it down ?

Comment: `projectData` is undefined on the initial render, and all subsequent renders, until it is populated by the data fetch call. You should either provide a valid object to destructure from or use a null check to do some conditional rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to initialize the **projectData** value as an empty object or render the jsx when projectData is not undefined.

```
const [projectData, setprojectData] = useState({});
    useEffect(() => {
        Axios.get(`/fetch-project-details/${id}`, {
            headers: {
                "x-access-token": localStorage.getItem(`login`)
           }
        }).then((response) => {
            let result = response.data.recordset;
            setprojectData(result[0]); // store array in state projectData
        });
    },[]);
    
    
    return (
        <div>
        <h1>projectData.title</h1>
        ... other code
    
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

For the very initial mount of the Component the `projectData` is `undefined` that's why you're getting the error.

You put a check if it's updated with data you're fetching.

```
    return (
    
    <div>
    {projectData ? 
     <h1>projectData.title</h1> : 'loading'}
    ... other code
);
```

If you don't want to work in this way always put the initial value of the state as something that follows your upcoming data's structure for example the initial value of your state might be something like:

```
{title: ''}
```

But it's always safe to check the state before you access it

Answer (score 0):

Before the axios call returns, projectData is initialized with `undefined`. So, while React waits for the call to return so that you can set the projectData, it goes ahead and renders with what it has. You need to have some kind of default status (a loading image or some "Please wait" text is common). You'll want to return your default status if projectData isn't defined:

```
if (!projectData) {
  return <p>Loading. Please Wait...</p>;
}
```

Depending on how you expect the data to look, you may also want to add to that check that projectData.title exists and has a value you expect in it.